# Python - using multiprocessing with multiple args doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing with multiple args to print dummy values, but this doesn't seems to work. I get error

```
"f() missing 2 required positional arguments:..."
```

for the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class tryProcessing:
    def f(self, arr, arg1, arg2):
        print(arr + " " + arg1 + " " + arg2)

    def func(self, arr, arg1, arg2):
        arg1 = "hi"
        arg2 = "hello"
        arr_a = ['1','2']
        arr_b = ['3','4','5']
        p = Pool(Processes=2)
        p.map(self.f, [[a, arg1, arg2], [b, arg1, arg2]])
        p.close
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.s. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47506920/12171620), he did something similar, I don't understand why his works, and mine doesn't.

Comment: Do the arguments need to be in tuples instead? `[(a, arg1, arg2), (b, arg1, arg2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap), which expected the iterable to contain nested iterables of arguments to be expanded as function arguments. It uses star (splat) notation to expand, hence the name.

P.S. you never actually call `p.close` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 1):

You pass one arguments, and it's an entire list.

```py
test = map(lambda x : x, [[a, arg1, arg2], [b, arg1, arg2]]) 
print(next(test))
```

You can update you f func like this.

```py
def f(self, *args):
    arr, arg1, arg2 = args
    print(f"{arr} {arg1} {arg2}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couples of difference with your approach compared with the solution you posted it's link there.

- Notice positional arguments `def someaction(a, b=1, c=2, d=3)`
- And you don't have positional argument `def f(self, arr, arg1, arg2)`

That might explain the error you are getting above.
Tweaking your code this works

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class tryProcessing:
    def f(self, arr):
        print(arr)

    def func(self, arr, arg1, arg2):
        arg1 = "hi"
        arg2 = "hello"
        arr_a = ['1','2']
        arr_b = ['3','4','5']
        p = Pool(2)

        data = [["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"],
        ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"],
        ["a3", "b3", "c3", "d3"], ]

        p.map( self.f, data)
        p.close

t = tryProcessing()
t.func("adfasf", "dfaf", "daf")
```